# POST method not allowed with gulp proxy server

Tags: proxy, gulp, http-post, proxy-server

I'm trying to use gulp to setup a proxy server using [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).
This actually works for GET requests. For POST requests I receive a HTTP Error 405: "Method not allowed". When bypassing the prxoy, the POST request works flawlessly.

I configured the proxy in gulp as follows:

```
var proxy = proxyMiddleware('/service/resources', {
    target: 'http://localhost:8082',
    changeOrigin: true,
    headers: {
        allow: 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS'
    }
});
```

Is this the way to go, or should I try an other approach?

Comment: Please provide more info on the middlewares you're using in your server.